# Google Play, application not compatible with Samsung Tablet

Tags: android, google-play

After publishing our app on GooglePlay and install it on several devices everything seems to be work fine, but some tablet appears on the store as "not compatible".

The tablet is a Galaxy Tab 2 (10.1)

This is some of result of our package $ aapt dump badging:

```
sdkVersion:'7'
targetSdkVersion:'17'
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

Our tablet has 4.0.4 and after checking the Downloads Statistics devices with that version installed it, Also sent the package via email to install and runs ok without any problem on that device.

Any tip would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this 3 things:

1 - Disable 'touchscreen'.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"  android:required="false" />
```

this disables ADVANCE touchscreen controls (like flicking etc.)

2 - Disable the Copy Protection in the Play Store Publish page if you use it.

3 - Also in your manifest file, you can try something like:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: They are both added, as we may see on my post $ aapt returns: `supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'`